# Select Mirror error

Tags: mirror, error, select

Select mirror is not working on my object. The object as a whole is asymmetrical but the selected edges are mirrored from each other. I did export the low poly model as an OBJ file from Zbrush if that matters. The origin of the object is at 0, 0, 0.

https://gfycat.com/foolishdismalgoldfish

[image]

Comment: are you sure they are mirrored? perhaps share your file or at least a part: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Yes, I did my retop in Zbrush with mirroring on for that part of the model. I uploaded the blend if you'd like to look at it.

Comment: Hello :). Your mesh isn't centered on the X axis. Its about 233mm off. That could cause your problems. The origin is centered allright, but the mesh is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never use this mirror selection tool but it looks like you need to have your origin on the middle of your object if you want it to work, so move your origin.

[image]